# mysql_real_escape_string () different behaviour on localhost and server, php5.1 , php5.4

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Before i call this question, yes i know mysql_query is a bad practice but i need to fix this first then in the near future i will move to PDO or something ok..

I have a code that works perfectly in localhost using php 5.4 the problem is when i load it in server, everything works fine, there is just one error, that at this moment , im blind at it.

On a description field, for a kind of articles in a blog, i use elrte and elfinder editor, the problem is when i send a image to store in de Database, i have different results.

In local i do store the `<img src="folder/ok/img.jpg">` but in the server for some reason the same files, and code store that in the database as `<img src="\&quot;/folder/ok/img.jpg\&quot;" >`

This must be related to this lines (the description file is going on `$desc`)

```
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){

            //protect and then add the posted data to variables
            $titulo = protect($_POST['titulo']);
            $desc = mysql_real_escape_string ($_POST['desc']);
            $cat_id = protect($_POST['cat_id']);
```

But can somebody explain this behaviour, cause im blind at this, also i know there are security issues on this, but well at least we are not storing any NASA info.

hope anyone can help me on this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without having looked too far into it, mysql_real_escape_string is deprecated and you should use [mysqli_real_escape_string()](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.real-escape-string.php) now (which goes with the new mysqli lib)

Comment: Ok but that will make me change everything in the site, cause if i use that i need to use mysqli in the db connection file wich makes all the queries in all the other files dont work.  Thats why i said, i know that, and in the future ofcourse i will update that, but for know need to understand why is working in local not in server, there must be a logical reason

Comment: Just for testing i did what you said, its not working it does exactly the same, why in local works good, and not in server with both mysqli or mysql.. thanks

Comment: i use html_entities to clean the quot stuff and then stripslashes() , but i do change to mysqli, and i just make a new con file

Comment: I've had similar issues with cleaning strings and I think I used html_entities as well to fix, try that. Otherwise, do you have error reporting set differently on live to local? Try setting error reporting to everything and see if it tells you anything.

Comment: i do have error reporting, but i do not know if it is enable for Everything.. i thougt it was until now jajaja

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure `$_POST['desc']` is the same on localhost and server? Maybe your POST request is being formed incorrectly

Comment: Its the same file, i mean i just move it and upload it, tested several times to confirm im using the exact same code